# Can I control the speed of this motor?

Tags: motor-controller

I have this motor from an older bandsaw that is broken. I would like to re-purpose it but I need to be able to control the speed. Is it possible with this motor and what would I need? I see people using light dimmer switches but wasn't sure that would work. Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UOlj.jpg)

Comment: That'll need a VFD (Variable Frequency Drive) to run at other speeds.

Comment: A VFD will be a problem, since it is single phase.

Answer (score 2):

That motor is a 4-pole induction motor - to change its speed, you would need to change its drive frequency - this is generally impractical for single-phase (which it is) motors, while 3-phase VFDs are pretty common.

Motors that are controllable with light dimmers are "universal" brush-type AC/DC motors which care only about voltage, not about frequency.

Your best bet for variable speed on that motor is a "Reeves drive" which is a variable-speed mechanical drive via variable-effective-diameter pulleys, or trading it for a different motor more suitable for electrical speed control. If only a few speeds are needed, a simpler step-pulley arrangement may do.

Comment: If the load is a fan, then the phase angle control would also work.

Answer (score 0):

Like a light dimmer, but for induction motors. They are built some differently, with additional resistors and caps, the simplest phase control dimmer for light bulb won't work at all speeds and your motor will cog, try and see. But you can control only a fan with phase angle control, since both fan and phase angle control will give you quadratic torque output function.